# Is it possible develop the conjugate of several complex numbers into the following expression?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Say one knows that the complex conjugate of two complex numbers written according to Euler's formula

$(e^{i\theta _{1}}+e^{i\theta _{2}})^{\ast }\times(e^{i\theta _{1}}+e^{i\theta _{2}})$

can be developed into

$2 + 2cos(\theta _{2} - \theta _{1})$

Does it work in a similar fashion with more than two complex numbers?

So

$(e^{i\theta _{1}}+e^{i\theta _{2}}+...+e^{i\theta _{n}})^{\ast }\times(e^{i\theta _{1}}+e^{i\theta _{2}}+...+e^{i\theta _{n}}) $

Would be developed into something like

$2 + 2cos(\theta _{2} - \theta _{1}) + ... + 2cos(\theta _{n}-\theta _{1}) + ...$

So the question is, does the concept work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a similar formula for $n$ unitary complex numbers. I just developed the product:
\begin{align*}
\overline{\big(e^{ix}+e^{iy}+e^{iz}+\cdots\big)}\big(e^{ix}+e^{iy}+e^{iz}+\cdots\big)&=\big(e^{-ix}+e^{-iy}+e^{-iz}+\cdots\big) \big(e^{ix}+e^{iy}+e^{iz}+\cdots\big)\\[1ex]
&=e^{-ix}e^{ix}+e^{-ix}e^{iy}+e^{-ix}e^{iz}+\cdots\\
&\quad\, \, e^{-iy}e^{ix}+e^{-iy}e^{iy}+e^{-iy}e^{iz}+\cdots\\
&\quad\, \, e^{-iz}e^{ix}+e^{-iz}e^{iy}+e^{-iz}e^{iz}+\cdots\\[1ex]
&=1+e^{-i(x-y)}+e^{-i(x-z)}+\cdots\\
&\quad\, \, e^{i(x-y)}+1+e^{-i(y-z)}+\cdots\\
&\quad\, \, e^{i(x-z)}+e^{i(y-z)}+1+\cdots\\[1ex]
&=n+2\big(\!\cos(x-y)+\cos(x-z)+\cos(y-z)+\cdots\big).
\end{align*}
So you get $n$ plus double the sum of the $n(n-1)/2$ cosines of the differences.

Comment: Cheers, Andrés!